# DirectX 11 Glowing Effects

Tags: graphics, directx

I have a quick question about some effects in DirectX 11.

As part of my Final Year Project, I am recreating the solar system. The atmospheres on planets look fine, but I am really struggling to get a nice glowing effect on the sun.

If you look at some images of stars in Elite: Dangerous, you can see the nice glowing effects created - I wish to create something similar to that. As an overview, what would be a way of going about achieving this effect?

Also, as a side question, for solar flares would particles be recommended? Or a different approach altogether?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Blooms & glows (and many other special effects) are generally achieved with post processing. See the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) tutorial lesson [Writing custom shaders](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20custom%20shaders) which demonstrates a bloom/glow implementation for Direct3D 11 in C++.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I shall have a look into that!